# Need to Return all Available Time periods per Day per Location

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I would like to find out how to 'roll up' the following table in Example 1 into Accumulated available time periods, as displayed in Example 2.
The following Code returns all the available Locations and the times that they are free by Day and by Half an hour timeslot.

I need to return the Available time in periods.  EG if a location is available from 9am to 5pm that should be displayed.

Code to return Data:

```
SELECT 
LTB.CalendarDate, 
LTB.VenueCode, 
LTB.VenueName, 
LTB.LocationCode, 
LTB.LocationDescription, 
LTB.OpenTime, 
LTB.CloseTime, 
LTB.Weekday, 
LTB.WeekdayName, 
LTB.MaxUniqueParticipants, 
LTB.TimeStartBlock, 
LTB.TimeEndBlock

FROM

--LTB

--TimeBlock
    (
            SELECT              LocationsOpenClose.CalendarDate,
                                LocationsOpenClose.StartTime, 
                                LocationsOpenClose.EndTime, 
                                LocationsOpenClose.VenueCode, 
                                LocationsOpenClose.VenueName, 
                                LocationsOpenClose.LocationCode, 
                                LocationsOpenClose.LocationDescription, 
                                LocationsOpenClose.Weekday, 
                                LocationsOpenClose.WeekdayName,
                                LocationsOpenClose.MaxUniqueParticipants, 
                                LocationsOpenClose.OpenTime, 
                                LocationsOpenClose.CloseTime,
                                TimeDimension_2.[Time] AS TimeStartBlock, 
                                DATEADD(SECOND, 1799, TimeDimension_2.[Time])
                                AS TimeEndBlock
--Locations Open Close

               FROM            (SELECT        
                                    dbo.LocationRoster.CalendarDate, 
                                    dbo.LocationRoster.StartTime, 
                                    dbo.LocationRoster.EndTime, 
                                    dbo.Venues.VenueCode, 
                                    dbo.Venues.VenueName, 
                                    dbo.Locations.LocationCode, 
                                    dbo.Locations.Description AS LocationDescription, 
                                    DateDimension.Weekday, 
                                    DateDimension.WeekdayName, 
                                    dbo.Locations.MaxUniqueParticipants,
                                    TimeDimension.[Time] AS OpenTime, 
                                    TimeDimension_1.[Time] AS CloseTime
                          FROM      dbo.LocationRoster 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.Locations ON dbo.LocationRoster.LocationGUID = dbo.Locations.LocationGUID 
                                    INNER JOIN DateDimension ON dbo.LocationRoster.CalendarDate = DateDimension.[Date] 
                                    INNER JOIN TimeDimension ON dbo.LocationRoster.StartTime = TimeDimension.MinuteFromMidnight 
                                    INNER JOIN TimeDimension TimeDimension_1 ON dbo.LocationRoster.EndTime = TimeDimension_1.MinuteFromMidnight 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.Venues ON dbo.Locations.VenueGUID = dbo.Venues.VenueGUID) AS LocationsOpenClose 

                    RIGHT OUTER JOIN  TimeDimension TimeDimension_2 ON TimeDimension_2.[Time] BETWEEN LocationsOpenClose.OpenTime AND DATEADD(SECOND, -1, LocationsOpenClose.CloseTime)
                        WHERE (LocationsOpenClose.CalendarDate BETWEEN '2018/08/15' AND '2018/08/16') ) AS LTB 
--CETB
    --CalendarEntriesStartFinish
        LEFT OUTER JOIN

        (
                    SELECT        

                    CalendarEntriesStartFinish.CalendarEntryDate, 
                    CalendarEntriesStartFinish.VenueCode, 
                    CalendarEntriesStartFinish.VenueName, 
                    CalendarEntriesStartFinish.LocationCode, 
                    CalendarEntriesStartFinish.LocationDescription, 
                    CalendarEntriesStartFinish.BookingStartTime, 
                    CalendarEntriesStartFinish.BookingEndTime, 
                    TimeDimension_2.[Time] AS TimeStartBlock, 
                    DATEADD(SECOND, -1, TimeDimension_2.[Time]) AS TimeEndBlock,
                    CalendarEntriesStartFinish.ReferenceGUID


                    FROM            
                        (
                            SELECT       
                                    CONVERT(DATE, dbo.CalendarEntries.StartDateTime) AS CalendarEntryDate, 
                                    dbo.Venues.VenueCode, 
                                    dbo.Venues.VenueName, 
                                    dbo.Locations.LocationCode, 
                                    dbo.Locations.Description AS LocationDescription, 
                                    CONVERT(TIME, dbo.CalendarEntries.StartDateTime) AS BookingStartTime, 
                                    DATEADD(SECOND,-1,CONVERT(TIME, dbo.CalendarEntries.FinishDateTime)) AS BookingEndTime,
                                    dbo.CalendarEntries.ReferenceGUID
                            FROM    dbo.CalendarEntries 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.Locations ON dbo.CalendarEntries.LocationGUID = dbo.Locations.LocationGUID 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.Venues ON dbo.Locations.VenueGUID = dbo.Venues.VenueGUID
                            WHERE (dbo.CalendarEntries.CalendarEntryType IN (0, 2)) AND (dbo.Locations.IsScheduled = 1)
                                    ) AS  CalendarEntriesStartFinish 

            RIGHT OUTER JOIN TimeDimension TimeDimension_2 ON TimeDimension_2.[Time] BETWEEN CalendarEntriesStartFinish.BookingStartTime AND CalendarEntriesStartFinish.BookingEndTime
                                WHERE (CalendarEntriesStartFinish.CalendarEntryDate BETWEEN '2018/08/15' AND '2018/08/16')
                                        ) AS CETB ON LTB.CalendarDate = CONVERT(DATE,CETB.CalendarEntryDate) AND LTB.LocationCode = CETB.LocationCode AND LTB.TimeStartBlock = CETB.TimeStartBlock 


WHERE (CETB.CalendarEntryDate IS NULL)
ORDER BY LTB.CalendarDate, LTB.LocationDescription, LTB.TimeStartBlock
```

Example 1: Current Result

```
CalendarDate    VenueCode   VenueName   LocationCode    LocationDescription OpenTime    CloseTime   Weekday WeekdayName MaxUniqueParticipants   TimeStartBlock  TimeEndBlock

15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  08:30:00    08:59:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  09:00:00    09:29:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  11:00:00    11:29:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  11:30:00    11:59:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  12:00:00    12:29:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  12:30:00    12:59:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  16:00:00    16:29:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  16:30:00    16:59:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  17:00:00    17:29:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  17:30:00    17:59:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  18:00:00    18:29:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  18:30:00    18:59:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  19:00:00    19:29:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  19:30:00    19:59:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  20:00:00    20:29:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  20:30:00    20:59:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  21:00:00    21:29:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  21:30:00    21:59:59
```

The above shows all the available times by half an hour.  It shows that A Location is not available from 13:00 to 16:00 on 15th August.

Example 2: Desired Result

```
CalendarDate    VenueCode   VenueName   LocationCode    LocationDescription OpenTime    CloseTime   Weekday WeekdayName MaxUniqueParticipants   TimeStartBlock  TimeEndBlock
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  08:30:00    12:59:59
15/08/2018  VC  Venue Name  Lcode    A Location     05:30:00    22:00:00    4   Wednesday   20  16:00:00    21:59:59
```

So that they know A Location is free between 05:30 and 08:30 and then again between 16:00 and 22:00

The Time Dimension table is split in half hour intervals.

A colleague has suggested below, but I cannot get it to work.

```
WITH t AS (
 SELECT LTB.CalendarDate d,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LTB.CalendarDate) i
  FROM @d
GROUP BY LTB.CalendarDate
)
SELECT MIN(d),MAX(d)
FROM t
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(day,i,d)
```

My SQL is not amazing so full explanations please, your help is appreciated.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 or 2016? There's a lot of functionality that was added in those 8 years.

Comment: Also, it seems you forgot to ask your question when you posted your "question". you might want to add that. The volunteers here can't help you if they don't know what you need help with.

Comment: Have amended post to ask question.  Thought the examples were self explanatory, apologies.

Comment: if you make a table of 'seconds in a day' as time (yes there are quite a few of them for your case where you work in seconds) then you can join your results to that and make it into an 'islands' problem with 1's and 0's for times in and out of a open section, then using some methods with row_number or rank, you can very nicely summarise to the max and min of the islands.  Without sample data and a table structure, or some simplification in your question, that is too hard to show you though but the technique is on-line 'sql islands problem'

Comment: - maybe if I assumed Example 1: Current Result was queried into a temporary table, I could show you from that

Comment: Thank you.  I have tried the query with a table of seconds in a day, it runs for over 5 mins at which point I stop it.  I will look up SQL Islands Problem.  The data could be sent to a temporary table.  The data returned at the moment is 12544 rows.  I realise the question is very complicated.  The simplification of the question is difficult.  The question is to find all half hour time slots in a locations calendar remove the bookings and just show the available times by time blocks.  eg.  Location A is available from 13:00 to 21:00 on 15th August.

Comment: mine is probably worse, since it is seconds in a day - maybe you could use a recursive CTE to join contiguous time periods, or even use  a cursor or program loop to condense a temp table down into contiguous start and end times, then simply query it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example, with my own test data

```
--build some sample data
select * into #tempt from 
(
SELECT cast('20180515' as date) calendardate,  'VC' as VenueCode, CAST('08:30:00' as time) opentime, CAST('08:59:59' as time) closetime union
SELECT cast('20180515' as date) calendardate,  'VC' as VenueCode, CAST('09:00:00' as time) opentime, CAST('09:29:59' as time) closetime union
SELECT cast('20180515' as date) calendardate,  'VC' as VenueCode, CAST('09:30:00' as time) opentime, CAST('15:59:59' as time) closetime union
SELECT cast('20180515' as date) calendardate,  'VC' as VenueCode, CAST('16:30:00' as time) opentime, CAST('18:30:59' as time) closetime union
    SELECT cast('20180515' as date) calendardate,  'VX' as VenueCode, CAST('08:30:00' as time) opentime, CAST('08:59:59' as time) closetime union
SELECT cast('20180515' as date) calendardate,  'VX' as VenueCode, CAST('09:00:00' as time) opentime, CAST('09:29:59' as time) closetime union
SELECT cast('20180515' as date) calendardate,  'VX' as VenueCode, CAST('09:45:00' as time) opentime, CAST('15:59:59' as time) closetime union
SELECT cast('20180515' as date) calendardate,  'VX' as VenueCode, CAST('16:45:00' as time) opentime, CAST('18:30:59' as time) closetime union
SELECT cast('20180515' as date) calendardate,  'VX' as VenueCode, CAST('18:31:00' as time) opentime, CAST('22:30:59' as time) closetime



) dq

--now do the work
--build a 'seconds in day' table using the first 3 CTE tables, 
;with secs as (select 0 sc union all select sc + 1 from secs where sc < 59),
      hrs as (select 0 hr union all select hr + 1 from hrs where hr < 23),
      allt as (select dateadd(SECOND, s1.sc + m1.sc * 60 + h1.hr * 3600, CAST('00:00:00' as time)) t from secs s1, secs m1, hrs h1),
      island as (select SQ.VenueCode,allt.t, case when exists(select 0 from #tempt tm WHERE SQ.VenueCode = tm.VenueCode and allt.t BETWEEN tm.opentime and tm.closetime) then 1 else 0 end x from allt cross join (SELECT distinct t3.VenueCode FROM  #tempt t3) SQ),    --calculation starts here
      calc as (select VenueCode,t,x,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by venuecode order by t) - ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by venuecode,x order by t) z    from island)              --asigns a number to all in an island
      select VenueCode,x,MIN(t),MAX(t) from calc group by VenueCode, x,z having x = 1 order by venuecode, MIN(t)                                --summarises islands




--clear test data
drop table #tempt;
```

Comment: Works fine in the test with the temp table, same problem with very long run time as soon as seconds and minutes are added.  I feel that the assigning the number to row and summarise  will work.  but getting into my query is a little beyond me at the current time.  I will keep looking and see what I get.  Many thanks for your help and suggestions.  They put me on the right track.

Comment: This works perfectly for one location,  if I try with two it returns only the first and last 'Freetime'.  eg: if free between 10am and 11am then 2pm to 3pm it will show free from 11am to 10pm.

Comment: Worked, but I needed to make a dim time that was 15 minutes and one that was just minutes.  Returned the dataset to a temp table and then ran the suggested code and it work. thank you.